# Валидация форм Symfony

Tags: form, безопасность, symfony, валидация

Помогите разобраться с принципом валидацией форм в Symfony.

Создаю поле в форме:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Наименование'
            ));
    }
```

В данном случае, согласно документации, поле `name` по умолчанию будет `required`.

Теперь если в браузере зайти в исходный код и удалить `required="required"`, а поле оставить пустым - форма, разумеется успешно отправится, и, самое интересное, что `$form->isValid()` будет `true`. При том, что в сущности это поле не может быть `null`.

```
/**
* @var string
*
* @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
*/
private $name;
```

В чем тогда суть валидации формы, если все равно придется проверять все поля вручную? Или я чего-то не так делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все дело в том, что у тебя в Entity нет ограничений. Проверка осуществляется путем добавления набора правил (так называемые ограничения) к классу.
Вот пример:

```
/**
* @var string
* @Assert\NotBlank()
*
* @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
*/
private $name;
```

[Документация тут](http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html), раздел Form Validation.

Comment: Не дочитал, видимо. Спасибо.

Comment: Не работает, проверяю на тип int, ввожу 123 - ошибка из сообщения, что я написал, ввожу 123a - This value is not valid. Т.е. 123 просто не int, а 123a - совсем не int?